# how many samples needed to obtain an estimate with a given confidence interval

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling, confidence-interval

Suppose an urn contains *N* balls of different colors. I do not know the colors nor the distributions, and I wish to determine the fraction of red balls in the urn, (*R/N*), to within *p*% with *C* confidence. I may repeatedly sample 1 ball with replacement. How do I know when I can stop sampling? (Note that *R* may equal zero.)

Comment: What is your sample size $n$ in each iteration?

Comment: Sample size _n_ = 1, with replacement.

Comment: When you say "within $p\%$"  is $\frac{2}{25}$ $4\%$ away from $\frac{1}{25}$, or $100\%$?